What would the appropriate cost be for a magical set of full plate with a Cast On and Cast Off property?
There is a common rarity armor enchantment called "Cast-Off armor" that allows the armor to be doffed in a single action. In this campaign, we're increasing the cost of common rarity magic items by 100gp, so Full Plate with the Cast-Off enchantment would cost 1600gp instead of the usual 1500gp.
What would be the appropriate fair price for Cast-On and Off armor, which allows you to don or doff the armor with an action? It is functionally identical to one benefit of the Artificer's Armorer subclass feature Arcane Armor (without any other benefits of that feature).
By comparison normally donning heavy armor takes 10 minutes and doffing it takes 5 minutes.
For context, we're using the Sane Magic Prices homebrew to help balance magic item prices based on their utility as well as their rarity.

The opposite of "Cast Off" is of course "Henshin!"

Price premium should be meaningfully more than 200 GP, significantly less than 800 GP
Mithral Armor is a good proxy for the utility of this armor, and Sane Magic Items values it at an 800 GP premium over the base armor cost. The major advantage of Cast On/Cast Off armor is being able to immediately remove penalties to Stealth by taking it off, donning it again when you need the protection more than the Stealth. Mithral Armor never imposes Stealth Disadvantage, saving the action required to remove it and don it again.
The things Cast On/Cast Off armor provides that plain Cast Off armor or Mithral don't provide are:

Sleeping in Mithral full plate would impose the (optional) Xanathar's penalties for sleeping in heavy armor; Cast On/Off armor could be easily removed to sleep, and donned quickly upon waking (e.g. in the event of nighttime random encounter).
Non-quantified social benefits (not typically something magic items are priced around) of being able to both have your armor available at a moment's notice and not suffer the stigma of being an uncouth soldier in polite society
Weird interactions with Warforged Integrated Protection feature (depends how DM rules on the interaction; there's no obvious answer there)

If the ability can be combined with other armor abilities (armor could be Cast On/Cast Off and provide another magical benefit), you'd want to be more careful, because there is a risk of the players carrying around multiple suits of armor to allow rapid retooling for new foes, but that's expensive and bulky and not likely to be a big problem.
Personally, I'd probably split the difference, and impose a price premium of around 400 GP (so Cast On/Cast Off Full Plate would cost 1900 GP). Donning armor takes longer, so the Cast On ability saves you more (so it should be more than double 100 GP), and interacts in a non-linear manner in increasing the armor's utility (so, even more than "more than double" in value), but the action cost to gain the AC benefits again after a period of Stealth is pretty significant if you have to pay it during combat, so it should cost appreciably less than Mithral. I wouldn't want it any lower because those other, less immediately combat/stealth benefits are useful, no question, so 400 GP feels about right.

Two words: Heat metal.

@Kirt: True, though plain Cast Off armor handles that one already, so the incremental benefit is just being able to don it again quickly after the one minute (or broken concentration) duration expires. Given the combat is likely over by then (and if it isn't, it can be hard to justify blowing an action that might end it to don the armor again), I'm not inclined to increase the price further to account for that benefit. It's also more of an issue for PvP (not usually that important a concern), given that few (no?) published monsters have the spell.

My party is in Dungeon of the Mad Mage.  Last session they fought a quaggoth thonot.  Otherwise good points.

Thanks for taking the time to post such a well thought out answer. I'll be curious to see if there are other opinions, but this is a great perspective. Thanks!
